# Operations on rows of dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 4 dataframes each with 3 columns and 10 row.  The first column is a dimension, while the latter two columns are values.   My goal here is to take loop through the list and rows of each dataframe and take variance of the 2 value columns for each record in each dataframe.  So the desired output would be a list of 4 dataframes with 2 columns, the dimension column, and the variance column.

Below is a sample where x is the dimension and y1 and y2 are the measures (my actual list has 5 dataframes with 15 values and ~9000 rows each).  This is just to simplify it.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

```
[[1]]
    x y1 y2
1   1  3  3
2   2  4  4
3   3  5  5
4   4  6  6
5   5  7  7
6   6  8  8
7   7  9  9
8   8 10 10
9   9 11 11
10 10 12 12

[[2]]
    x y2 y2.1
1   1  2    3
2   2  3    4
3   3  4    5
4   4  5    6
5   5  6    7
6   6  7    8
7   7  8    9
8   8  9   10
9   9 10   11
10 10 11   12

[[3]]
    x y3 y2
1   1  4  3
2   2  5  4
3   3  6  5
4   4  7  6
5   5  8  7
6   6  9  8
7   7 10  9
8   8 11 10
9   9 12 11
10 10 13 12

[[4]]
    x y4 y2
1   1  5  3
2   2  6  4
3   3  7  5
4   4  8  6
5   5  9  7
6   6 10  8
7   7 11  9
8   8 12 10
9   9 13 11
10 10 14 12
```

Comment: If you show us `dput(small_version_of_your_thing)`, it will be easier to try out a solution. Anyway, my guess is: `lapply(x,function(DF) cbind(dim=DF[[1]],var=apply(DF[,2:3],1,var)))`

Comment: Are you trying to compute variances for two observations each time?

Comment: @Frank I think the margin is `1`  for the `apply`, though not sure :-)

Comment: @akrun Ah, thanks! I always get it wrong and have to switch. :)

Comment: Any how, if are to compute a variance per row, I would suggest to vectorize it using some vectorized custom functions such as `RowVar <- function(x) {
  rowSums((x - rowMeans(x))^2)/(dim(x)[2] - 1)
}` for example. `apply` is *always* my last resource.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying ot compute the variances for the two measure columns for each row in each dataframe of the list

Comment: @akrun I don't like the concept of computing a variance on two observations...

Comment: I think the original dataset have 15 columns/values (that is what i interpreted)

Comment: It's not actually two observations. I just created a simple list of dataframes to make it easier to think about.  Obviously a variance for two obs would be kind of silly.

Comment: @Frank you can post a solution using "my" uber vectorized row wise function if you want.

Comment: Can we get a `dput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
lapply(x,function(DF) cbind(
  dim = DF[,1],
  var = apply(DF[,2:3],1,var)
))
```

*@DavidArenburg's improvement*: For improved efficiency, replace the `apply` call with

```
var = RowVar(x[,2:3])
```

where

```
RowVar <- function(x) {
  rowSums((x - rowMeans(x))^2)/
  (dim(x)[2] - 1)
}
```

[Noam Ross makes the argument](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html) for vectorization (like `RowVar`) over `*apply`.

*Aside*. If you had a list of matrices instead of data.frames, this might be faster. As they all have the same dimension, you might even think of putting them in a three-dimensional array.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was looking for a reference on the inefficiency of `apply`. Or is there a different reason to avoid it?

Comment: `apply` is just a `for` loop so it is obviously not vectorized. It is becoming especially inefficient when operation per row. Even `data.table` isn't efficient when operating per row.

Comment: Btw, I have a Gist of bunch of these vectorized functions which you can source using `library("devtools"); source_gist("cca995ec1709c0d4735d")`